# How to have responsive title and avoid cropped title?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

For a shiny application, I am generating multiple plotly graphics: titles varies depending on the parameters chosen by the user. Sometimes titles are too long and get cut off, so they are not fully visible. They also get cut off when the screen size changes. How can I make the title adjust to the size of the graph and be fully visible?

Thank you for your help.

```r
# data for example :
m <- structure(list(Frequency = c(3826, 2766, 676, 337), Percent = c(50,36, 9, 4)), row.names = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
# plot example 
plot <- plot_ly(m,x = m$Percent, y = rownames(m), type = "bar",
                orientation = "h",
                marker = list(color = '#10367a')) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "Too long title. It's cropped and i want that it is automatically re ajusted to be diplayed !"),
         xaxis = list(title ="x axis", range = c(0, 100)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y axis"),
         showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

...since you said you're using Shiny.

I don't know what your app looks like, so I can't tell you the ideal sizing for your title. The formula I used for the dynamic title size is in the code comments.

The values I used allow the title to be as small as 14px and as big as 30px depending on the width of the viewscreen.

BTW:  I think the `plotly` default is that the title font size is 20px.

In your `ui` add the following.

```
  tags$head( 
    tags$style(HTML(                                # dynamic title size
      "g.infolayer g.g-gtitle text{
        font-size: calc(14px + (30 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))) !important;
      }"))
    # font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * 
    #     ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - 
    #     [minimum viewport width])));
  )
```

`minimum viewport width` and `maximum viewport width` are both in pixels. 1600 is a decent-sized monitor, while 300 is smaller than most phone screens.